# how do I unit test jersey webservices?

Tags: netbeans, jersey

Any one know any good step by step guides for unit testing jersey webservices in netbeans?  I am using restlib_gfv3ee6 lib for jersey and it seems not to include the jersey test framework.  I have trying to follow http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e759 but the instructions are vague and the example is poor.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to follow is the section about testing Jersey clients. You want [Chapter 7, The Jersey Test Framework](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.12/test-framework.html).

**Update:** "good to see some blog references"...

You mean like [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_makes_it), [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/naresh/entry/jersey_test_framework_re_visited), [this](http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/rest-assured-vs-jersey-test-framework-testing-your-restful-web-services/), [this](http://www.mentby.com/glassfish/jersey-test-framework-custom-messagebody-readerwriter.html), or [this](http://shotgunsandpenguins.blogspot.com/2011/04/effective-testing-of-jersey-resource.html)? Google's an amazing thing, ya know.

Comment: This is a good starting point, but it would still be good to see some blog references to this practice of testing.

Comment: @boo: Updated my answer, as it wouldn't fit in a comment.